# What's an easy way to access prebuild macros such as $(SolutionDir) and $(DevEnvDir) from code in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, prebuild

Right now I'm thinking write the paths to a file in the pre-build event and then read from that file in the code, but I'm wondering if there's an easier more elegant way.

edit: This is sort of a follow up to [Help with one step build all projects + installer (.NET + WiX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480748/help-with-one-step-build-all-projects-installer-net-wix) since I didn't really get an answer to that, seeing if I can get an answer to a simpler question.

Comment: Very interesting what for do you need to know the solution path?

Comment: Basically trying to create a 1-step build process without hardcoding in the paths since it needs to work on different build machines

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a dirty hack: dump them to a file.

1. Add an action to the pre-build events to output your solution's path to a file:

   `echo $(SolutionDir) > SolutionDirFile.txt`
2. Read the file `SolutionDirFile.txt` in your C# code.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking, but was wondering if there was a cleaner solution, but I guess that should work.  This answer saves me finding how to write it to a file from the prebuild, so accepted it.

Comment: At first I was thinking, "Ouch. That's **ugly**." But after an hour of searching, this is the only solution that actually does what I need. +1

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I think one of the ways you could get this information into the file at compile-time is by using something like PostSharp. Basically, get some sort of preprocessor to get the data for you, and then simply embed it in your assembly.