# Find Working Project Directory in C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I have used Directory.getCurrentDirectory();

its giving only C:\Windows\SysWOW64

but i need to get the visual studio default project folder how can i get that ?

ex:C:\Users\knallasi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SampleApp

how do we find that above project location ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What type of application is it?  I'm asking bec. I wonder if your process context might be a service (like the iis app pool maybe)

Comment: gabriel, its XBAP application wpf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about the PROJECT directory, but the directory of the executing assembly can be found by using

```
string currentAssemblyDirectoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

usually, if you're executing in Visual Studio, the project directory is up two levels, you you could trim "bin\release| or "bin\debug" of that string to get the project directory, but that's a bit of a hack.  I'm not sure there is a way to get the project directory from code.

Comment: thanks david this is what i too thought already but trimming "bin\debug" is the only thing we want to do !

Comment: System.Reflection.Assembly, in case you are not "using" it already

Answer (score 1):

After lots of searching I found the "dirty hack" solution for accessing things like $(ProjectDir) from within your code.

[What's an easy way to access prebuild macros such as $(SolutionDir) and $(DevEnvDir) from code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481063/whats-an-easy-way-to-access-prebuild-macros-such-as-solutiondir-and-devenv)